# How do I create a hyperlink that sends together with an E-mail message?

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a hyperlink that sends together with the E-mail. I've tried to find information on how to do this but I keep hitting a brick wall.

The third $message. variable should have a hyperlink but I dont seem to make it work. How do I make a hyperlink out of the third $message. variable and how do I include it in the mail function?

**The PHP code for sending mail and hyperlink**

```
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
$from=$_POST['minemail'];
$email=$_POST['kanemail'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$message.="<br>Klicka på den här länken för att påbörja provet\r\n";
$message.="welcomeuser.php?passkey=$confirm_code"; //hyperlink

$company="dashboardcompany.php";

$sql= "INSERT INTO temp_members_db(confirm_code, email) VALUES('$confirm_code', '$email')";


$result=$connect->query($sql);


mail($email, $subject, $message, "Från: ".$from);

print "Ditt meddelande har skickats: <br>$email<br>$subject<br>$message<br>";
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: this is HTML 101 stuff. Plus, you need to use a full http:// call when hyperlinking, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: put it in href in a tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrape text with HTML tag for url. Just use something like:

```
$message.="<a href=\"http://www.example.com/welcomeuser.php?passkey=$confirm_code\">"; //hyperlink
```

Answer (score 1):

When including a hyperlink via Email/Internet, a full (external) http:// call is required, otherwise when a user clicks on the hyperlink, it will try and open a document from the user's (local) computer.

```
$message.="<a href='"."http://www.example.com/welcomeuser.php?passkey=$confirm_code".">welcomeuser.php?passkey=$confirm_code</a>";
```

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

On an added note:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: this will fail since it will try and open a non-existant document on a user's computer, rather than from a webserver.

Comment: that's simple dear.. please use the complete url then like "http://www.example.com/welcome.php"

Comment: don't tell me that, modify your answer accordingly. it isn't my question and I know this already.

Comment: i have edited my answer. Please do check

Comment: [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345315/how-do-i-create-a-hyperlink-that-sends-together-with-an-e-mail-message#comment56432494_34345440) was in regards to their original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34345440/1 - `<a href='"."welcomeuser.php?...`

Comment: okay surely it may be but i am talking about the latest edit...

Comment: and I was talking about your original post. That isn't my downvote btw.

Comment: okay anyways thanks...

Comment: You're welcome. I made an edit to your answer in order to improve it. I hope you have "learned" from this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance and support sir. I m glad atleast I learnt something today.

Comment: It was my pleasure, *cheers*